# Spring/Hibernate multiple data sources with foreign key between them

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Say I have two tables, in different schemas. Therefore, I create an entity and transaction manager for each data source:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.(omitted).endpoints.all.endpoint.crm",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "crmEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "crmTransactionManager"
)
public class PersistenceCrmConfig {

  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;

  public PersistenceCrmConfig() {
    super();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean crmEntityManager() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    bean.setDataSource(crmDataSource());
    bean.setPackagesToScan("com.(omitted).data.all.model.crm");

    ...
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager crmTransactionManager() {
    ...
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public DataSource crmDataSource() {
    ...
  }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.(omitted).endpoints.all.endpoint.user",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "userEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "userTransactionManager"
)
public class PersistenceUserConfig {

  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;

  public PersistenceUserConfig() {
    super();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManager() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    bean.setDataSource(userDataSource());
    bean.setPackagesToScan("com.(omitted).data.all.model.user");

    ...
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager userTransactionManager() {
    ...
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public DataSource userDataSource() {
    ...
  }

}
```

In the `user` data source (schema), I have the entity, `User`, that has a one-to-one mapping to the entity, `Person`, in the `crm` data source (schema).

```
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false)
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Person person;
```

This causes an exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/(omitted)/endpoints/all/spring/PersistenceUserConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.(omitted).data.all.model.user.User.person references an unknown entity: com.(omitted).data.all.model.crm.Person
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.(omitted).endpoints.all.Application.main(Application.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.(omitted).data.all.model.user.User.person references an unknown entity: com.(omitted).data.all.model.crm.Person
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1823) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1767) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

I understand why I get this error. Spring must generate two Hibernate Session Factories and therefore, two lists of entities that know nothing about each other.

How can I get the one-to-one mapping to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make it work with two Hibernate Session Factories.
I also would not recommend trying to force Hibernate to create a single one for this case.

Easies workaround I see is on the DB side.
Consider creating a view of `person` table in your `user` schema and map your `Person` entity to the view, not to the table.

This approach will not allow you to update the `person` table using your `userEntityManager` (unless you are using Oracle DB). If you need to do it at some point, you can use your `crmEntityManager` to find the corresponding `person` in the table and update it.

Keep in mind, that transactionality may be harmed if you have to update both `person` and `user` as a part of a single operation due to the same reason you mentioned (different Session Factories).